# Stop multer file upload on user's request

Tags: node.js, file-upload, multer

i want to implement a code where after clicking on upload button, if the user wants to stop/cancel the upload then he can do that.
so how to stop the multer uploading if the user presses cancel button while uploading the file?

this is my multer storage:

```
var CVstorage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        const dir = __basedir + "/uploads"
        return cb(null, dir)
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, file.originalname);
    },
})
```

and this is how i am calling multer upload function:

```
router.post('/upload/video/:week', (req, res) => {
    var uploadCV = multer({ storage: CVstorage }).single('videoFile_' + req.params.week)
    uploadCV(req, res, err => {
        console.log(req.file)
        if (err) {
            res.send(err)
        } else {
            res.send('uploaded')
        }
    })
})
```

this is how m sending file for multer to upload

```
var input = document.getElementById("Video");
var file = input.files[0];

var idxDot = file.name.lastIndexOf(".") + 1;
var extFile = file.name.substr(idxDot, file.name.length).toLowerCase();

if(extFile == '.mp4' || extFile == '.mov') {
    var form = $('#uploadVideo')[0];
    var data = new FormData(form);
    $.ajax({
        xhr: function() {
            var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt) {
                if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                    var percentComplete = ((evt.loaded / evt.total) * 100);
                    $("#progressbar").width(percentComplete + '%');
                    $("#progressbar").html(Math.round(percentComplete)+'%');
                }
            }, false);
            return xhr;
        },
        type: "POST",
        enctype: "multipart/form-data",
        url: "/upload/video/" + week,
        data: data,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        beforeSend: function(){
            $("#progressbar").width('0%');
        },
        success: (data) => {
            alert(data)
        },
        error: (e) => {
            alert(e.responseText)
        }
    });
} else {
    alert('only .mp4 / .mov files allowed')
}
```

Comment: There are multiple ways to do this on the client side. It depends on how you upload the file. Do you use axios, jQuery, XMLHttpRequest or ...?

Comment: m doing the file uploading like this... (have editing the question)

Comment: So simple `xhr.abort()` should work.

Comment: yeah that worked. Thank you.